# XML serializer not able to Deserialize array correctly

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm getting XML in following format:

```
<Order>
    <OrderData>
        <OfferOrder></OfferOrder>
        <OfferOrder></OfferOrder>       
    </OrderData>
</Order>
```

Now when I'm Deserializng string `orderxml` containing the XML, It doesn't fill `<OfferOrder>` into my `OrderData` object.

```
XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer((typeof(Order)));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(orderxml))
{
    order = (Order)xmlserializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

**Classes**:

```
public partial class Order
{
    private OrderOrderData orderDataField;

    public OrderOrderData OrderData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderDataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.orderDataField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class OrderOrderData
{
    private OrderOrderDataOfferOrder[] offerOrderField;

    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrder[] OfferOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return this.offerOrderField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.offerOrderField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is something wrong with my classes?

Comment: Simpelst way is defined [this post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code. First you can make your properties to auto-implemented properties, that is omit the private backing-fields and write this instead:

```
public MyType MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Second you have to provide the names of the tags within the Xml to the serializer. In your case the names within the xml and those in your class-structure are equal, so you can omit the names also. However just for completeness:

```
public class Order
{
    [XmlElement("OrderData")
    public OrderOrderData OrderData { get; set; }
}

public class OrderOrderData
{
    [XmlElement("OfferOrder")
    public OrderOrderDataOfferOrder[] OfferOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The reason why it doesn´t work for you is that arrays are usually serialized with a nested element whose name in your case would be `OfferOrders`. Within that tag you have then the arrays elements. Usually it´s not wanted to have that further nesting, what you want instead is to flatten the elements of the array directly into your actual data-class. To do so add an `XmlElement` upfront your array-declaration with the name of the **elements**, in my code `OfferOrder`.

Comment: I suspect another problem arising from "partial" ( `public partial class OrderOrderData` )

Comment: @HimBromBeere `the type or namespace XmlElement could not be found`

Comment: Then add it: `using System.Xml.Serialization;`.

Comment: @Fildor What´s whrong with a partial class? I think this should work.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Nothing wrong with it in general. But we cannot see the other "parts" ... so there may be additional problems there, but we cannot see it in the snippets given.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Got it. Works!